# Required to put roof or door overhang on a sliding door?

Tags: doors, roof, sliding-glass-door

I have no experience in architecture or house building. I am currently brainstorming a house design and I am thinking of putting a sliding door as one of the entrance to the house aside from the main door. Is it required or advisable to out a roof that will cover the sliding door considering it gets quite rainy in my country? The house is 2 story and the roof on the 2nd floor should be able to cover the space but not sure if it will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I know that in the USA sliding glass doors can leak if directly exposed to rain, which can be windblown.

Comment: @FreeMan Any sliding “door” (glass or otherwise) will leak when exposed directly to the wind and rain.

Comment: Very true, @LeeSam. However, when I wrote that comment, the answer was talking about an overhead garage door. It's been edited since & my comment deleted.

Answer (score 0):

My personal experience would suggest that "it's advisable" though it's not specific to "a sliding door" particularly - I have a (slightly taller than average) 2-story building with generous roof overhangs (2 feet, or about 600mm) and I have found that I want "small roofs right over doorways" due to rain blowing sideways far enough to hit the door openings down at first floor level despite the overhang.

The roof edge is 20-25 feet (6-8 meters) above ground level.